# Javascript Get Prototype Function Name

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes

Disclaimer: This code was written by another developer, previously on the project and I can't change it - I'm not allowed too.

What I'm trying to do is get the name of the parent(?) function within `this.foobar()` from `BaseDialog`.

Is it possible?

```
var BaseDialog = new function () {
   this.foobar = function () {
      // get the prototype function name that called me? E.g DialogOne
   }
}

DialogOne.prototype = BaseDialog;

function DialogOne() {
   this.foobar();
}

DialogTwo.prototype = BaseDialog;

function DialogTwo() {
   this.foobar();
}
```

Comment: what's the code you can't change and which one is yours?

Comment: @Argee I'm not sure I understand you. The snippet I posted was all from another developer. I didn't write any of it.

Comment: @Bergi I agree which is why I mentioned it was done by another dev, who previously worked on this and not me. I've only posted a very very small snippet of the functions here to give you an idea. These dialogs are heavily integrated across the project I'm working on ATM and rewriting everything again is not possible. I'd love too but not allowed.

Comment: @Bergi - Not sure why you deleted your comment? Anyone reading this will be confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let callerName = arguments.callee.caller.name.toString();
console.log("caller is " + callerName );
```

Comment: the `toString` is printing out the whole function - is it possible just to get the "DialogOne" for example ?

Comment: So `arguments.callee.caller.name` did the trick!

Thank you so much!